# Doctrine and MySQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine, database-connection

I have few questions about Doctrine and MySQL working together. I don't understand it in 100%

I read somewhere that Doctrine can cooperate with MySQL DB. How it happens?

1. How do I load my DB?
2. How do I operate on my MySQL tables via doctrine (I'm no thinking about creating new ones)?
3. Does Doctrine save automatically changes to database?, if not then how to?

Some sample of code would be great. I don’t care too much about language can be in PHP, Yaml and others.

Comment: what you mean with "load my DB"?

Comment: Does doctrine not have documentation with examples? I think that should be the first place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) please specify more what you maen with "load DB". Doctrine is an ORM.
check here docs:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/hu (check cookbook)

b) operations with tables with Doctrine are with DQL, example:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('User u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers p');

$q->execute(); //you get a doctrine collection to iterate results of query
```

c)NO you need to save the object

```
$account = new Account();
$account->name = 'test 1';
$account->amount = '100.00';
$account->save();
```

here is account class

```
class Account extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 255);
        $this->hasColumn('amount', 'decimal');
    }
}
```